# How can I read the entire Solidity warning in the Remix browser?

Tags: solidity, remix, warnings

When I get a Solidity warning in the Remix browser, I can usually just hover over the warning symbol to the left of the editor and read the error message. But, this time the end of the error message is off the screen to the right. How can I capture/see the rest of the off-screen message? The only way I've found, so far, is to zoom out the whole web page. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Analysis tab on the top right of Remix, there you can see the details of all the warnings.

[image: remix screenshot]

Comment: I checked there, but did not see the same warning. I'm referring to the warnings that appear as yellow triangles with an exclamation point just to the left of the code line numbers.

Comment: I see what you mean those are in the Compile tab if you scroll down you can see it.

Comment: Yes, that's it. The same warning was found in the "Compile" tab. Case closed! ;)